# Table too wide for page in standalone file?

Tags: tables, floats, standalone

My goal is to create a standalone TeX file containing tabulated figures.  No matter what value I set for image width, the resulting table is always too wide for the page. Here is a MWE:

```
\documentclass[varwidth]{standalone}
\usepackage[pdftex]{graphicx}
\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage{lscape}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{subfig}
\def\ig{\includegraphics[width=1in, keepaspectratio]}


\begin{document}
\begin{figure}[!htbp]
\begin{tabular}{p{0.2cm}ccc}
 R1& \subfloat{\ig{example-image-a}} 
   & \subfloat{\ig{example-image-b}} 
   & \subfloat{\ig{example-image-c}}\\[0.4cm]  
   &C1&C2&C3 \\
\end{tabular}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Drop the `geometry` package (or use its `pass` option). Also, a `float` environment like `figure` seems misplaced in a `standalone` document. Why do you use it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The call to `geometry` is wrong, and also `lscape` doesn't make sense.

Also `figure` and `\subfloat` are not necessary: `\includegraphics` can go *anywhere*, it's treated just like a big letter.

```
\documentclass[border=1,varwidth]{standalone}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\newcommand\ig[1][]{\includegraphics[width=1in, keepaspectratio,#1]}


\begin{document}
\begin{tabular}{p{1cm}ccc}
 R1& \ig{example-image-a}
   & \ig{example-image-b}
   & \ig{example-image-c} \\[0.4cm]
   &C1&C2&C3
\end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

The definition of `\ig` allows for additional options.

[image]